# Unable to uninstall express in Ubuntu 13.x

Tags: node.js, express

I have express installed, but it no longer works. When I type 'express' in the terminal I get:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/express: No such file or directory
```

If I try and uninstall I get...

```
sudo npm uninstall –g express
npm WARN uninstall not installed in /home/user/expressApps/sausage/node_modules: "–g"
npm WARN uninstall not installed in /home/user/expressApps/sausage/node_modules: "express"
```

Or if I try and re-install I get...

```
sudo npm install –g express
npm WARN package.json application-name@0.0.1 No README.md file found!
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/3.12.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/%E2%80%93g
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/%E2%80%93g
npm ERR! 404 '%E2%80%93g' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-24-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "–g" "express"
npm ERR! cwd /home/johnmlocklear/expressApps/sausage
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! code E404
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express/3.12.1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/johnmlocklear/expressApps/sausage/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

How can I get express working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think my issue was that I had installed express from the apt-get repo using

```
sudo apt-get install express
```

Then after that at some point I also had installed from npm. To clean all this up I ran

```
sudo apt-get uninstall express
```

...and I also went into ~/.npm and removed both express and express-genrator folders. I then ran both...

```
sudo npm install -g express
sudo npm install -g express-generator
```

...and all seems to working OK now.

Comment: That solved my problem, Thanks and plus one though.
But there is one more thing, I installed npm by using npm .. its weired but that's the only way I could install npm properly `sudo npm install npm`

Answer (score 1):

The big clues to me are in these error lines:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/%E2%80%93g
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/%E2%80%93g
npm ERR! 404 '%E2%80%93g' is not in the npm registry.
```

That `%E2%80%93g` (note the `g` at the end) seems crazy. And it seels to be directly connected to this line:

```
sudo npm install –g express
```

That `–` next to the `g` is not a simple dash but some UTF-8 character that has been url encoded. Pretty sure [that is an en-dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) since a url encoded `%E2%80%93` equals `e28093` in hex [as shown here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm). That most likely came from a copy & paste out of a text editor that somehow automatically sets simple dashes to en-dashed. Be careful of stuff like that when storing code & cheats heats.

To fix it, run the command with a real dash `-` like this:

```
sudo npm install -g express
```

The other issue I see is this:

> bash: /usr/local/bin/express: No such file or directory

So where is that `/usr/local/bin/express` coming from? If `express` wasn’t in your path then you wouldn’t even get a full-path message like that? Is that a `bash` alias in your profile? If you set that yourself, I would highly recommend just adding `/usr/local/bin/` to your shell path instead of setting an alias.